# wp-cli configuration in php?

Tags: wp-cli

https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/#config-files is pretty good, but I'd like to have some more logic in my configuration.  Is there a standard way for this?

For `drush` I have `.drush/aliases.drushrc.php`, which includes scripts from various Drupal repositories, which in turn contain the logic to handle various sites and variations (production, development). I'd like to have something similar for `wp-cli`, and YAML doesn't provide me with the right tools for what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The WP CLI aliases are mostly for context. WP CLI uses Drush as a source of inspiration, but Drush has a much more robust implementation of aliases.

If it were me, I would include other scripts and complex logic as a custom command.

`WP_CLI::add_command( 'core foo', 'Foo_Command' );`